# remove the class which have a specific string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to remove the class which have a specific string.
I did try the following but it does not work.

```
<body class="myClass someStringAndOtherString"></body>

$('body').removeClass('class', ':contains("someString")');
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you want to remove the class someString, or you want to do something else?

Comment: something else.. I updated my question which was not clear!

Comment: Downvote to your question for a) posting a question which conveys wrong info, b) your attitude of downvoting people's comment when they try to help you!

Comment: @PulkitMittal  I down-voted people just because I was thinking my question was clear :( . then I understand to get wrong :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove the class 'someString' do the following:

```
$('body').removeClass('someString');
```

To remove all classes if the 'someString' class is found:

```
$('body').hasClass('someString').removeAttr('class');
```

To remove a class that contains a string:

[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/JKuPD/)

```
// test if someString is present
if( $('body').attr('class').indexOf('someString') != -1){
     // get classes as array
     var classes = $('body').attr('class').split(' ');
     // loop over array
     for(i=0;i< classes.length; i++){
          // is this class a class that contains someString?
          if(classes[i].indexOf('someString') != -1){
              // remove said class
              $('body').removeClass(classes[i]);
          }
     }
}
```

Or here it is as a function:

[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Y9hUR/1/)

```
function removeClassesThatContainString(selector, someString){
    var $selector = $(selector),
        classAttr = $selector.attr('class');
    if(classAttr.indexOf(someString) != -1){
        var classes = classAttr.split(' ');
        for(i=0; i<classes.length; i++){            
            if(classes[i].indexOf(someString) != -1){
                $selector.removeClass(classes[i]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

then it would be:

```
removeClassesThatContainString('body', 'someString');
```

Comment: @LorraineBernard just for the record, its pretty rude to ask your question one way, get people to answer it the way you wrote it. Then change your question and downvote people's answers.

Comment: @LorraineBernard It will also decrease the likelihood of people answering your questions, as they would not want to be downvoted.

Comment: @GrailsGuy you know groovy and grails? Hit me up!

Answer (score 0):

```
$('body').removeClass('someString');
```

If the class would exist on several places:

```
$('.someString').removeClass('someString');
```

*edit*
Answer to new question:

```
$('[class*="someString"]').each(function () 
  var classes = $(this).attr('class').split(' ');
  for(var i = 0; i < classes.length; ++i) {
    if(classes.indexOf('someString') >= 0) {
      $(this).removeClass('classes[i]);
    }
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code.

```
$('body').removeClass(function(i,c){var classes=c.split(' ');for(var i=0;i<classes.length;i++){if(/someString/.test(classes[i]))return classes[i];}});
```

It will remove classes like someStringAndOtherString, thissomeString and someString.

In the case of multiple classes, it will only remove the one that matches, so, in your example, it will leave the 'myClass' class alone.